# What does the log line "not enough directory information to build a circuit" mean?

Tags: bridge, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy, consensus

I just changed tor bridge type from obfs3 to obfs4. What's the meaning of the bold sentence? BTW, Tor connection is fine. (Win7 user)

> 2016-01-18  7:26:51.800 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'xxxxx' (fresh): $xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxx at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> 2016-01-18  7:26:51.800 [NOTICE] **I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus.**
>
> 2016-01-18  7:26:56.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network

Answer (score 1):

It is just normal. It means Tor client did not finish fetching consensus, and as soon as it finishes, it starts to build circuits.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that when you're changing bridge type, the Tor node needs to re-announce itself. Try to play with theese options, see details in [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) :

- `ExtORPort` - it helps to use pluggable transports explicitly
- `ConnLimit` **and** your OS fd limit, in Linux it's `ulimit -n` output. The more connections you can make - the more connectivity you will have
- IPv6/IPv4 coexistance : sometimes if you're using IPv4 to reach an outer internet, you need to **completely disable** IPv6 on sysctl level and when compiling libraries. The core of the problem is that some dual-homed hosts are resolved/mapped to IPv**6** and the software stack tries to use it. If you have only IPv4 address - try to disable the IPv6 completely : somtimes it speeds up twice